# Integração GlassFish com Eclipse Photon

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

Alguém já usou glassfish com eclipse photon? Como fazer a integração?
Já tentei de várias formas e nada. Não instala o plugin do glassfish.
Testei com o eclipse oxigen e também não tive sucesso. Alguém poderia me ajudar?
Já pesquisei e não achei a solução.

Comment: Qual a versão do glassfish que você tem instalado em sua máquina? Precisa mesmo ser glassfish ou poderia ser um autoembarcado para desenvolvimento, como o Jetty?

Comment: A versão que tenho é a versão 5. Infelizmente eu preciso usar o glassfish.